# iTunesConnect no longer allows tester gmail with plus sign?

Tags: gmail, app-store-connect, sandbox

In the past, I used to use the same Gmail address for testing in-app purchasing (sandbox testing) by adding + sign to my email. For example, `myemail+testapp@gmail.com`

Now I am no longer able to create such user as I get the error:

> This email address is not available for use as an Apple ID. You may already have an Apple ID associated with this address. Please try again or sign in using your existing Apple ID.

I read that Google did not disable this as I can still us it on other places. But not any more on iTunesConnect Sandbox user page.

Can anyone confirm this?

Is there a way around this aside from creating a new Apple ID for each new tester?

Comment: I can confirm this as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am seeing the same thing. It's weird because the title of the validation popup says that the password is the problem.

[image: validation popup]

For what it's worth I'm using a temporary email provider and just generating a new email each time I need one.